# Is there a way of checking the window's focus (not the document) from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, focus, cross-domain

I see numerous questions along these lines, but they all require checking the document object. I'm trying to do this from a cross-domain iframe, so I don't have access to top.document. Any way to do with with the window.top object?

UPDATE: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140826/is-there-a-way-of-checking-the-windows-focus-not-the-document-from-javascript/8141339#8141339) below

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is no.  Such things are the responsibility of the document and not the window.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283278/checking-the-windows-focus-constantly/4283302#4283302), which uses window.onfocus and window.onblur. Unfortunately browser security seems to prevent attaching events to window.top.onfocus/blur....